# Limit of a sequence further maths

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hi I am doing further maths, at gcse.
I am really stuck on finding the limit of $\frac{2n+5}{4n-1}$
as well as $\frac{1-6n}{2n+3}$

Please could someone try explaining this to me.

Comment: As a first step, divide numerator and denominator by $n$.

Comment: What does $n$ tend to ? Infinity ?

Comment: The intuition with limits like this is to see that as $n$ gets large, the $+5$ in $2n+5$ isn't going to matter (is there really that much difference between $10$ billion and $10$ billion and $5$?). Ditto for the $-1$ in $4n-1$. The answers you see here are just ways of justifying that instinct rigorously.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

*Factor out* $n$ from each of the numerator and denominator.

E.g. $$a_n =\dfrac{2n+5}{4n-1} = \dfrac{n(2 +\frac 5n)}{n(4 - \frac 1n)}$$
Cancel  the common factor.
$$a_n = \dfrac{2 + \frac 5n}{4 - \frac 1n}$$

Now evaluate the limit as $n \to \infty$: each fraction (in numerator and denominator) will approach zero as $n\to \infty$, so you will be left with a limit of $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{2 + \frac 5n}{4 - \frac 1n} = \dfrac{2+0}{4 - 0} = \dfrac 12$$

---

Apply the same approach in order to evaluate the second limit.

Answer (score 0):

Try put $n$ in evidence. For example, $$\frac{2n+5}{4n-1} = \frac{n(2 + \frac{5}{n})}{n(4 - \frac{1}{n})} =\frac{2 + \frac{5}{n}}{4 - \frac{1}{n}}$$
Now, the numerator tend to $2$ and the denominator tend to $4$, when $n\to\infty$. So 
$$\frac{2n+5}{4n-1} \to \frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$$